# How much memory does Ubuntu Server on a VPS need?

Tags: server, 10.04, vps

I'm wondering will I be able to run Ubuntu 10.04 on a VPS with 256 RAM, and if not, what's the best OS to run on that VPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This VPS is more than enough for a Ubuntu Server but not enough for a normal Ubuntu with the graphical environment ([Ubuntu minimum requisites](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)). If your python script doesn't need to draw things, it will be ok.

If you need to run a graphical Ubuntu with only 256Mb your best option is [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)

Note that usually a VPS offers assume that you will use the server version and don't make any provision for graphical access.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I bought it today and installed everything. It works how I wanted it to work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can see the minimum system requirements here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#System_requirements

**Installing from the CD requires a minimum of 256 MB of RAM.**

But there is one operating system that comes to mind: puppy linux. Maybe that's an option.
People have succeeded in running **Puppy** with a **333MHz CPU and 64MB**. To be comfortable 256MB RAM and a 512MB swap file will run smoother.

Comment: Oh well, the plan that I've choosen has 256 MB + 256 MB burstable. I guess if I change it to 384 MB (it has 512mb burstable too) I will be able to run Ubuntu + my python script. Correct me if I'm wrong.